# Submit button in partialview return result without layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a shared layout with partialView for login in it.
If login process succeeded it redirect to main page and everything works, but if login failed,
It returns only the partial view with the errors without the shared layout.

The result is a page with this url : `localhost:35967/Account/Login` with only the partialview contains the validation summary errors.

How to fix it ?

Here is my code:

AccountController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel login,string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ValidateUser(login))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, false);
                return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User not found");
        }

        return PartialView(login);
    }
```

Login.cshtml

```
@model DesignCrafts.MVC.Models.LoginModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "login", @class = "enter_form" }))
{
<span style="color:red">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed")</span>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Username, new { @placeholder = "username" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)

    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @placeholder = "password" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)

    <input type="submit" value="login" class="btn" />

    <span style="margin-right:5px">
        @Html.ActionLink("register", "Register", "Account", new { @class = "white-link"})
    </span>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "user not found")

}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
     @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
     {
        <div class="enter">
        <div>
        Logged as: @User.Identity.Name
        </div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Log out", "Logoff", "Account", null, new { @class = "exit" })
        </div>
      }
     else
      {
          { Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account"); }
      }
```

Comment: just apply condition also on login and based on that load layout

Comment: @Exception can you be more specific ? where should I apply the condition ? and what condition ?

Comment: what exactly you want...??? @Ido

Comment: @Exception Sorry, but I didn't understand your answer. where exactly should I apply the condition ? and what condition ? thanks

Comment: @Ido..just clarify me exactly what u want...plz commnet clearly your reuirement...

Comment: 1.What is the condition that I need apply? 2.Where should I apply it? 3.What I need to add to my code ? 4. The code should apply to httpGet or HttpPost ? @Exception

Comment: as far as i m understanding your problem just include @{Layout="// Path of layout page //"} just after @model at the top of login partial.

Comment: @Exception No... it causes IISExpress 8.5 to crash!